# BroadcastReceiver doesn't receive anything after being force killed then restarted

Tags: android

I have a BroadcastReceiver that I register dynamically in the `onCreate` method for my Service.  It receives the action fine at first, but if the app is force killed and then restarted it doesn't receive anything.

The reason I'm force killing is that I'd like to test my app from a completely unstarted state, and even when I do "stop process" from Eclipse there seems to be some part still running.  Also, I feel like it should be able to handle being force stopped from the user, right?

The BroadcastReceiver is registered with:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
registerReceiver(btReceiver, filter);
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you register in onresume and unregistered it in onpause method ??? if not making it and it will work fine with you

Answer (score 4):

> I have a BroadcastReceiver that I register dynamically in the onCreate method for my Service. It receives the action fine at first, but if the app is force killed and then restarted it doesn't receive anything.

I am assuming that "force killed" means that you went into Settings and pressed the "Force Stop" button. If so, there are multiple reasons for this.

Tactically, if you register a `BroadcastReceiver` via `registerReceiver()`, it will only be available until the corresponding `unregisterReceiver()` call, or until your process is terminated if you leak the receiver.

Even if you move the receiver to be registered in the manifest, if you force-stop your app, that receiver will not receive any more broadcasts, until the user runs your activity (or something else triggers your code via an explicit `Intent`).

> The reason I'm force killing is that I'd like to test my app from a completely unstarted state, and even when I do "stop process" from Eclipse there seems to be some part still running

When you terminate your process using DDMS, your process is no longer running.

Comment: Sorry you're right - the process is no longer running.  The problem is the service still is, and it restarts my process.  Is there a way to kill processes and also services associated with my app?

Comment: @user693861: "The problem is the service still is" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly? If your process is terminated, and you're not doing something screwy with multiple processes, your service is not running. "and it restarts my process" -- that's because your `onStartCommand()` is returning something like `START_STICKY` or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, saying that you *want* Android to restart your service sometime after your process has been terminated. " Is there a way to kill processes and also services associated with my app?" -- no, but you could fix your `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: On the device, I open "Application Manager" and swipe over to the "Running" tab.  My app is listed as having one process and one service running.  When I press "Stop process" from DDMS in Eclipse, it says 0 processes but still 1 service.  The "time running" field says "Restarting...", and after a couple seconds it lists 1 process as running.

It was returning `START_STICKY`, so I'll change that and see what happens, thanks.

Comment: Update: I changed to `START_NOT_STICKY`, but the service is still restarted after around 30 seconds.  Also, if I stop my app from DDMS and then start it again (by clicking the its icon on the device), I don't receive any BroadcastReceiver actions again.

Comment: @user693861: "Update: I changed to START_NOT_STICKY, but the service is still restarted after around 30 seconds" -- try completely uninstalling the app, then installing it again. "I don't receive any BroadcastReceiver actions again" -- presumably you are not going through your code path that calls `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: `Even if you move the receiver to be registered in the manifest, if you force-stop your app, that receiver will not receive any more broadcasts` why? I thought android will create process to deliver broaadcasts registered in manifest. What if android kills my app, or it crashes?

Comment: @marcin_j: "why?" -- because that's the way they wrote Android 3.1, to help block drive-by malware. "What if android kills my app, or it crashes?" -- neither of those are equivalent to force-stopping your app. On most devices, the only thing that force-stops your app is the user clicking the "Force Stop" button in Settings. There appear to be some devices where the manufacturer added their own task manager that also force-stops apps, and that was an unfortunate choice on their part. Normal process termination is not a force-stop and does not affect future broadcasts.