# why not working broadcast receiver when application closed in 4.4.4 version in xiomi prime 2 mobile?

Tags: android

```
     **
```

> strong text

**I am using Broadcast Receiver in Incoming Call.But My question is that Receiver did not work after application kill.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean application is force-killed. Then this is expected behavior. Please refer this discussion for clearer understanding - [BroadcastReceiver doesn't receive anything after being force killed then restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296345/broadcastreceiver-doesnt-receive-anything-after-being-force-killed-then-restart).